# Si actualizo mi app Android se borran los datos de la base Sqlite?

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, android-layout, android-sqlite

**Hola tengo una aplicación en la App Store y la quiero actualizar. Si la actualizo se borrarán los datos que hay en la base de datos? Por ejemplo la gente que se ha registrado perderá su cuenta?

Que alguien me ilumine please**

Comment: Tienes las cuentas registradas en una base de datos sqlite? localmente? o entendí mal? por favor describe mejor el manejo que haces de la base de datos.

Comment: Yo cree la base  de datos Sqlite con android studio. Y me he dado cuenta que por ejemplo cuando ejecuto el emulador e inicio sesion la cuenta funciona pero he probado con mi telefono movil y me dice que esa cuenta no existe. Creo que la base de datos no se exporta a otros dispositivos. Yo no soy experto en el tema de manera que no se a que te refieres con "local". Segun me habian dicho Sqlite no necesita un servidor para administrar la base de datos simplementa la creas en android studio y deberia funcionar.

Comment: Hola veo no has realizado el [tour] ni visto el documento [ask]. Te comento que en este caso es importante el código en particular tu clase que extiende de SQLiteOpenHelper-

Comment: @Jorgesys fijate en esta pregunta.. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98315/tengo-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-local-como-puedo-conseguir-que-haya-persistencia .. no son dupli.. pero son casi la misma pregunta...

Comment: como la base de datos es *local*, **sólo funciona en ese dispositivo**, no hay manera de que, si tu creas un usuario en el emulador o X telefono, al usarlo en el tuyo no podrás iniciar sesión, puesto que la BD de tu celular es distinta a la BD del emulador. como opción, deberías implementar webServices y BD en servidor, para que múltiples dispositivos usen la misma BD.

Comment: Creo que todo dependera si tu BD esta en un webservice

Comment: Si, no has cambiado el diseño de tus datos, ni la versión de la base de datos, normalmente se conservan la información que tiene el usuario. Puedes hacer la prueba, instalando la versión antigua en un emulador, hacer que tu app guarde datos y actualizando con la nueva version que piensas publicar, asi sale de dudas. Saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si actualizas la app (`versionCode`) no se pierden los datos. Si modificas/actualizas la base de datos SQLite si pueden perderse los datos. Creo que lo más común es agregar una columna a una BD, por lo tanto hay que actualizar el código: en `DATABASE_VERSION` cambias a un número mayor, en `onCreate` agregas la columna nueva, y si no quieres que se pierdan datos ya guardados en la BD, utiliza el `ALTER TABLE` en el método `onUpgrade`. Ejemplo:

```
     @Override  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
      db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tutabla ADD COLUMN tu_nueva_columna INTEGER"); 
      //db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tutabla ADD COLUMN tu_nueva_columna");        // sin mencionar el tipo  
  } 
}
```